# Can I show Javascript functions defined in PHP functions inside Aptana Outline?

Tags: javascript, php, aptana, outline

I use jQuery and in PHP I've created a javascript object that mantains an array of javascript functions. This way I can maintain server scripting next to client scripting.

In PHP, I just do **javascript::add('function javascript_test(){ ... }');**

In the past I've been using Notepad++, which has a very basic outline view that manages to show PHP functions side by side with the javascript functions I define this way.

**Can I obtain the similar behaviour in Aptana (using, perhaps, comment tagging)?**

Comment: What you say "Aptana", ar you just referring to Aptana Studio, the IDE?

Comment: Javascript inside a string, inside PHP, quickly becomes an unmaintainable mess. I can only recommend that you don't go down that route. You might find a IDE which can highlight code inside strings, but most can't and it makes things harder to read and understand.